# Mysql and PhP updating only the first Row in the database? why?

Tags: php, mysql

There is a problem with my code, It is only affecting the first row in the database, WHY

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $query = "UPDATE databasename SET id=";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[id]. "', 1 =";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[1]. "', 2 =";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[2]. "', 3 =";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[3]. "', 4 =";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[4]. "', 5=";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[5]. "', 6=";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[6]. "', 7=";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[7]. "', 8=";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[8]. "', 9=";
    $query .="'" .$_POST[9]. "'";

    echo "USER has been modified";
    echo $query;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='http://www.example.com/instrument.php?id=$_POST[id]'>Click This Link </a>";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysql_error());
    header ("Location: edit.php");
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should really use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), or at least use the [`mysqli_real_escape_string` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Are your columns really named 1,2,3,4, etc?

Comment: You're using `mysqli_query` and `mysql_error()` - you need to stick with one library (and that should the `mysqli_*` one)

Comment: No this is just an example.

Comment: is databasename a table name ?

Comment: @user2409831 Does this code actually demonstrate your error? I'm guessing the parts you removed are the problem.

Comment: What does echoing `$query` produce?

Comment: You might want to use a WHERE clause when updating a table, And please post your real query otherwise this is useless

Comment: Also, echo out your query and see what it looks like. Try running that directly in the database and see what happens.

Comment: @j08691 Here's the query: `UPDATE databasename SET id='5055', 1 ='5055', 2 ='5055', 3 ='5055', 4 ='5055', 5='5055', 6='5055', 7='5055', 8='5055', 9='5055'` : Where all POST values are `5055`. I was looking at this myself...

Comment: I tried to echo the query and it looks fine nothing wrong with it

Comment: It works perfectly but only for the first row in the database, and it does affect the rest

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly *updating* the table and not *inserting*, then you need a `WHERE` clause to limit the update to the desired row. Your current statement does not have this clause, so it would update all rows in your table. Example:

```
$query = "UPDATE tablename SET 1 =";
//$query .="'" .$_POST[id]. "', 1 =";
$query .="'" .$_POST[1]. "', 2 =";
$query .="'" .$_POST[2]. "', 3 =";
$query .="'" .$_POST[3]. "', 4 =";
$query .="'" .$_POST[4]. "', 5=";
$query .="'" .$_POST[5]. "', 6=";
$query .="'" .$_POST[6]. "', 7=";
$query .="'" .$_POST[7]. "', 8=";
$query .="'" .$_POST[8]. "', 9=";
$query .="'" .$_POST[9]. "'";
&query .="' WHERE id=" . $_POST[id];
```

And yes, this is vulnerable to SQL injection as written.